# Is it ok to use two "of"s in a sentence

Tags: redundancy

I am currently writing a summary for a poison called "Wourali". One of the ingredients for it is two kinds of bulbous plants(specifically the stalks of them). Is this fine?

> They bind the vine with the stalks of two species of protuberant plants.

Comment: [Protuberant](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/protuberant) doesn't mean 'having tubers' (I assume that is what you meant, as you describe the plants as _bulbous_. Bulbs and tubers are not quite the same, though.)

Comment: What binds the vines?

Comment: wourali is also known as curare: it comes from the plant  Strychnos toxifera, which is a woody vine. https://www.britannica.com/plant/Strychnos-toxifera

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using *of* twice, in nested preposition phrases.

(What does *bind the vine* mean?)

Comment: I wouldn't of known what "nested prepositional phrases" were.

Comment: It means exactly that. tie and wrap up two stalks to a third.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Yes, because you are identifying the chartacteristics of two subsets.

Species and Protuberant plants. It gets repetitive if used more then twice though:

"...stalks of two species of protuberous plants of the deciduous family of the Neolithic era..."

:Prince Dudley of Whoville, Earl of Grinchland, Duke of Christmas town, heir to the throne of Whimsy World"

But don't quote me on those nonsense examples.